# Fail2ban и log файл в Debian 12

Tags: debian, логирование, fail2ban

Стоит свежий и чистый сервер на debian 12(amd64), соответственно работает sshd чтобы можно было подключаться через терминал. Установил fail2ban и при попытке его поднять он выдает ошибку о том что файл /var/log/auth.log не существует или неправильно указан путь, на самом деле его там и вправду нет, система его не создала, и при ошибочных попытках авторизации по ssh лог тоже не создается, как будто sshd на сервере не ведет логирование. Добавил в /etc/ssh/sshd_config LogLevel INFO и SyslogFacility AUTH, после перезапуска и попытки неудачной авторизации для проверки создания логов никакиго лога не создалось. При этом в journalctl все неудачные попытки авторизации отображаются. На чистом debian 11 файл /var/log/auth.log создается сам автоматиечески и fail2ban прекрасно работает, что не так с этой двенашкой и что можно сделать, может кто сталкивался с подобным?

Answer (score 0):

Решилась проблемка банально установив rsyslog )))

Comment: Достаточно было добавить в jail `backend = systemd` (тогда оно мониторит systemd journal, иначе файлы из `logpath`).